# is it possible use any jquery scrollbar in jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is it possible use any jQuery scrollbar in jQuery UI dialog?
I am using an iframe inside jQuery UI dialogue.
Is there any other way to style my scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, do some research - http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: @Xander - However it will be difficult ( not impossible ) to replace the iframe's scrollbar.

Comment: Why not just make a scrollable DIV then?

Comment: @KoryHodgson i want to style it.Cross Browser

Comment: What browser doesn't support divs?

Comment: @KoryHodgson i am talking about scrollbar not the iframe

Comment: Create your own scrollbar with divs and javascript if you want it to be cross browser